# Using reduced sample space for this question on biased coins

Tags: probability

I understand that this question has been asked before on this forum but, my question is not on how to do the question but on why my approach using reduced sample space fails.

Consider this question, also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505178/when-coin-1-is-flipped-it-lands-on-heads-with-probability-4-when-coin-2-is-fl):

> When coin 1 is flipped, it lands on heads with probability .4; when
> coin 2 is flipped, it lands on heads with probability .7. One of these
> coins is randomly chosen and flipped 10 times.
>
> (a) What is the probability that the coin lands on heads on exactly 7
> of the 10 flips?
>
> (b) Given that the first of these 10 flips lands
> heads, what is the conditional probability that exactly 7 of the 10
> flips land on heads?

For part (b), my initial approach was just to disregard the biasness of the coins, and just calculate the probability that 6 of the remaining 9 coins are heads, so the conditional probability is just $\frac{9\choose{6}}{2^9}$ because in the reduced sample space of 9 tosses, we want 6 of the tosses to be heads, the remaining 3 to be tails. Is there a reason why does this way of thinking is wrong?

Comment: I don’t quite understand your reasoning. You start by disregarding the biasness of the coins. It means that you should return to it in your reasoning later, but it never happens. Instead you are just solving an alternate problem, with unbiased coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... my question is not on how to do the question but on why my approach using reduced sample space fails.

Your approach fails because you are not using the information that the first toss landed heads (except to count 1 heads). Here's why that is a problem.

Coin 2 is significantly more likely to land heads compared to coin 1. So if the first toss landed heads, it's more likely (not certain though) that coin 2 is being used. You are not using this information at all.

Instead you are using the probability of landing heads for each of the remaining tosses to be $0.5$, which is simply not true.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. Would my approach be correct if we are dealing with a fair coin then?

Comment: If both the coins were fair, then yes. But in that case the question would look very different.